# Client side to server side calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I want to change the list of available values in a dropdown depending on the value selected in another dropdown and depending on values of certain fields in the model.  I want to use JQuery to do this.  The only hard part is checking the values in the model.  I have been informed that I can do this using Ajax.  Does anyone have any idea how I will approach doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is indeed the technology your looking for. It is used to sent an asynchronous request from the client browser to the server.

[jQuery has an ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that you can use to start such a request. In your controller you can have a regular method tagged with the `[HttpPostAttribute]` to respond to your AJAX request.

Most of the time you will return a JSON result from your Controller to your view. Think of JSON as something similar to XML but easier to work with from a browser. The browser will receive the JSON and can then parse the results to do something like showing a message or replacing some HTML in the browser.

[Here you can find a nice example](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/working-with-jquery-ajax-api-on-asp-net-mvc-3-0-power-of-json-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views) of how to use it all together.